# If condition vs loop one item

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, optimization

I was just curious, is it worth to have if condition before looping some array, that in 90% will be array of 1 item?
Code example:

```
const a = [3];
const aLength = a.length;
if(aLength > 1) {
    for(let i = 0; i < aLength; i++) {
        func(i);
    } 
} else {
    func();
}

function func(position = 0) {
  console.log('hi' + position);
}
```

Comment: It's much more important that the code reflect your intentions. Don't worry about tiny performance issues.

Comment: @Pointy I'm also interested in bad/good code practices, maybe it's forbidden or know-how, just wanted to know.

Comment: In this particular case I think it's more readable to *not* differentiate the two cases. The 1-element array is not a special case (i.e., it would behave exactly the same way if you didn't *force* it to look like a special case), and it does not behave differently than a bigger array.

Comment: Removing the if else would make the code shorter, more readable and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Write clean code and make everyone happy.

you can eliminate if and loop:

```js
   const a=[5,6,3]
   a.forEach((value,index)=>console.log('hi'+index));
```

Comment: Why `map` and not `forEach`?

Comment: yeah, **forEach** is better for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Federico's comment, a single for loop is the most readable in this case.

Also, even though you reuse it, there is not much point to extracting a.length into aLength

```
const a = [3];
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    func(i);
} 

function func(position) {
  console.log('hi' + position);
}
```

Warning: very personal perspective down there, you could achieve the same level of clarity with comments too.

Well, unless the single element case has a very specific meaning in your domain. In which case, I would separate them with two functions with very specific names as follows:

```
const a = [3];
if(a.length > 1) {
    handleMultiple(a);
} else {
    handleSingleAndWhyItIsASpecialCase(a)
}

handleMultiple(array) {    
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        func(i);
    } 
}

handleSingleAndWhyItIsASpecialCase(array) {   
    func();
}

function func(position = 0) {
  console.log('hi' + position);
}
```

As Hamid said below, you can easily turn it into a oneliner:

```js
[45,63,77].forEach((element, index) => console.log(index));
```

Consider using forEach instead of map to make your intent clear though.